# Including assets in sonata-project/block-bundle 4.0

Tags: php, symfony4, sonata-admin, sonata

Symfony sonata block bundle has twig function "sonata_block_include_stylesheets", which must register all blocks assets. But in **version 4**, i did not find how it can be do.
In **3.* version**, in services classes exist methods as "getJavascripts" and "getStylesheets".
I tried simple write `<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="{{ asset('some.css') }}">` on template, in hope that it will automatically include this script. But they only render this link in block html, but i want to group css links on top of the page.
Any ideas, how this make ?

Answer (score 0):

we dropped asset management for the 4 release, because this should be part of webpack or your custom template code.

Comment: Do you have link which described how now use function "sonata_block_include_stylesheets", that provide access to separeted files by blocks ?
As i understand, in webpack you mean - combine all scripts/styles in one file ? I don't like this method in time of actuality HTTP2.0